# Dart: Exit of a async method without any trace

Tags: dart, async-await

The following method will be reached. But none of the 3 logging statements will be fired.

```
    void readAndExecute(String sql, List parameters,
        CallbackOnSingleRow onSingleRow) async {
     _lastResults = null;
     await _dbConnection.query(sql, parameters).then((Results result) {
      _logger.log('something found', LEVEL_FINE);
      for (var row in result) {
        _lastResults ??= result;
        onSingleRow(row);
      }
     }).catchError((error) {
      _logger.error('read failed: $error\n$sql');
      throw DbException('readAndExecute()', sql, parameters, error.toString());
     });
     _logger.log('end of readAndExecute() reached', LEVEL_FINE);
    }
```

- _dbConnection is a valid MySqlConnection instance (successful login)
- sql is a valid SQL statement (tested with a DB tool):
- sql: select * from users where user_id > ?;
- parameters: [0]
- The logging of the packet mysql1 is activated, the output is:

```
FINE: 2020-05-10 11:33:40.060170: start handler Instance of 'PrepareHandler'
FINE: 2020-05-10 11:33:40.060748: sendBuffer header
FINE: 2020-05-10 11:33:40.060938: sending header, packet 0
FINE: 2020-05-10 11:33:40.061021: writeBuffer length=4
FINE: 2020-05-10 11:33:40.061091: _writeBuffer offset=0
FINE: 2020-05-10 11:33:40.061278: Wrote 4 bytes
FINE: 2020-05-10 11:33:40.061438: 
38 00 00 00                8···
```

I'm afraid I didn't understand something about the "async-await" concept.

After answer 1 the code is changed to:

```
    try {
      _lastResults = await _dbConnection.query(sql, parameters);
      _logger.log('result reached', LEVEL_FINE);
      for (var row in _lastResults) {
        onSingleRow(row);
      }
    } catch (exc) {
      _logger.error('readAndExecute(): $exc\n$sql');
    }
```

But the problem remains: the 2 loggings will not be reached.

Comment: You either use `await` and store the returned value as a variable, or use`.then()` and perform a function with the value you obtained within the `then`. I don't see the point of you calling both of them at the same time

Comment: You are right, that was a misunderstanding on my part. The await variant fits my requirement.

Comment: I have changed the code, but the problem remains.

Comment: put a logger above the `await` line and see if it prints

Comment: A logging statement above the await works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I simplified both versions of the code that you provided:

```
Future readAndExecute() async {
  print(1);
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((i) {
    print(2);
  }).catchError((error) {
    print(3);
    throw "thrown";
  });
  print(4);
}
// prints:
// 1
// 2
// 4

Future secondTry() async {
  try {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    print(1);
  } catch (exc) {
    print(2);
  }
}

// prints:
// 1
```

Talking about the second one, you should be seeing `result reached` (`1` in my example), if `_dbConnection.query(sql, parameters)` is indeed completing.

I would really make sure the functions are actually called. Put a log before anything else in the functions and see if you see it in your logs. So:

```
    _logger.log('CALLED INDEED', LEVEL_FINE);
    try {
      _lastResults = await _dbConnection.query(sql, parameters);
      _logger.log('result reached', LEVEL_FINE);
      for (var row in _lastResults) {
        onSingleRow(row);
      }
    } catch (exc) {
      _logger.error('readAndExecute(): $exc\n$sql');
    }

Future secondTry() async {
  print(0);
  try {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    print(1);
  } catch (exc) {
    print(2);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Gzihan: At first I thought: what does the code have to do with my problem? But the abstraction that doesn't work has shown that the problem is more fundamental. The real problem was that in the call stack contains a call without "await". Thank you.